# Unassigned Local Variable error when trying to download a file from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to download a file from database but its giving me an error called unaasigned local variable one the line: 
return bytes;

Please tell me how can I cast string to byte in my case, thank you in advance.

I have a column named SaleFileName from which I want to download a file.

Aspx code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RecieptName" SortExpression="RecieptName">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("SaleFileName") %>' Text='<%# Bind("SaleFileName") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind File:

```
private byte[] ReadFileFromDatabase(string FileName) {
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;  
    byte[] bytes;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "selectSaleFileName from Contributions where SaleFileName = @SaleFileName";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleFileName", FileName);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();

            using ( SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
               if (sdr.Read() )
                  bytes = (byte[])sdr["SaleFileName"];
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    return bytes; // This line is giving an error of unassigned error. Bytes is not assigned to anything it says.
    }
    protected void gridContributions_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
            string FileName = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);      
            byte[] bytes = ReadFileFromDatabase(FileName);

            Response.Clear()
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; FileName=" + FileName + ";");
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
            Response.End()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler can't determine whether `bytes` will be assigned any value by following static flow of the code.

You are initializing `bytes` inside an if statement, What if there are no rows returned from the database, then `bytes` would never be initialized.

You can assign some default value `null` to your `bytes` at the time of declaration like:

```
byte[] bytes = null;
```

The above declaration and initialization will remove the error, but it depends entirely on your requirements, whether you want to throw an exception or return null.

You may also see: [5.3 Definite assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691172%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> At a given location in the executable code of a function member, a
>   variable is said to be definitely assigned if the compiler can prove,
>   by static flow analysis, that the variable has been automatically
>   initialized or has been the target of at least one assignment

.

Comment: After making this change, on the scond last line i.e. Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); its giving an error called Object reference not set to an instance of an object. What should I change?